# Swift 2.0: How to disable current user from pressing button again?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I'm trying to implement a vote feature on my app. The user has to press a button to vote. After the user presses it, they should no longer press it again. I created an attribute for the users each time they voted(or pressed the button) through a PFRelation. I've also added a disable button method that would stop the user from doing this except my app crashes every time I do so. I think it may have to do with the way I structure the column in Parse but I like to hear other solutions to do this. The disable method I tried is below.

I've created a disable function:

```
func disableButton(button: UIButton){
    button.enabled = false
    button.userInteractionEnabled = false
    button.alpha = 0.5
}
```

It get's disabled here in my voteButton function:

```
@IBAction func voteButton(sender: UIButton) {
    disableButton(sender)

    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
     self.userVote?.addObject(object!)
    polls.addObject(object!)
    object!.incrementKey("voteUp")
    object!.saveInBackground()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    NSLog("Top Index Path \(hitIndex?.row)")
}
```

Here is where my app keeps crashing:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell? {
   let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PollCell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! PollsApp

if let userPolls : PFObject = self.polls.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject {


if let voteCount = object[("voteUp")] as? Int {
        cell.votersCounts.text = "\(voteCount)"
    }

  if (PFUser.currentUser()?["votedPost"] as! [String]).contains(userPolls.objectId!){
       cell.disableButton(cell. voteButton)
   }
```

Comment: what is the crash message?

Comment: What do you see in the crash report?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you even need to do this if it is a relation - I think that Parse doesn't allow the same user to populate a Relation twice...

Comment: Do you think I should call a better method for saveInBackground()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you force unwrap `PFUser.currentUser()?["votedPost"]` as a `[String]` it's failing because it's trying to force unwrap nil.

Change this:

```
if (PFUser.currentUser()?["votedPost"] as! [String]).contains(userPost.objectId!){
   cell.disableButton(cell. voteButton)
}
```

to

```
if let votedPost = PFUser.currentUser()?["votedPost"] as? [String] {
    if votedPost.contains(userPost.objectId!){
       cell.disableButton(cell. voteButton)
    }
}
```

Now, as to why `PFUser.currentUser()?["votedPost"]` is nil, that's a different question.

Comment: Well I'm using a PFQueryTableViewController and PollApp is the custom tableviewcell. I'm not getting an error there though. I'm getting the error where I the PFUser is written inside the tableView

Comment: Ok, I saw another place you're force unwrapping that is probably failing

Comment: Ok that stops the app from crashing. Thank you so much for that. But my question is also concerned with disabling the user from voting again after reloading the app. Anyway I can get help with that?